# Do constructors always immediately have access to the functions declared in their class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Take the following code snippet:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      name: 'Tyler'
    }

    this.updateName = this.updateName.bind(this)
  }
  updateName() {
    this.setState({
      name: 'Mikenzi'
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1>Hello, {this.state.name}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.updateName}>Change Name</button>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

I understand why the `bind()` call is required, as the scope that provides access to `this` will be lost when React calls `updateName` via the event handler.

What I'm not quite sure about is the relationship of `this.updateName` in the `constructor` function to the actual function declaration (the prototype property) further down.

Is the `constructor` function referencing `updateName()` as a pre-existing function (prototype), or is it creating an entirely new function? I think there is a syntax comprehension problem here. What is the actual process going on, and how does the actual function declaration relate to what is being referenced in the constructor?

Comment: Remember that your class is defined before it is used: the code in the constructor isn't run until you call `new` later in the program, well after the definition of the rest of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, class methods are available in the constructor. As evidence, try a simple class:

```js
class A {
    constructor() {
        console.log(this.method());
    }
    method() {
        return "This works";
    }
}

new A; // logs "This works"
```

That said, a common way of doing this in React is with class instance fields and arrow functions so the binding is done automatically. This would make your code look like this:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      name: 'Tyler'
    }
  }
  updateName = () => {
    this.setState({
      name: 'Mikenzi'
    })
  }
  ...
}
```

While there are downsides to this approach, potentially in terms of performance and testing, you might like to explore it as a possible approach.